How can I force SSMS to drop a temp table that has new columns?
I often use temp tables while researching data, and sometimes I'll create the table and then try to drop it and create a new one with more/different columns. SSMS does not like this. For example, if I run:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
SELECT 1 AS ColumnA, 2 AS ColumnB INTO #temp
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM #temp

It correctly returns 1,2.
However, if I then run:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
SELECT 1 AS ColumnA, 2 AS ColumnB, 3 AS ColumnC INTO #temp
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM #temp

I should get 1,2,3 since the table should have been dropped and a new one should have been created with the new column. However, I instead get: Invalid column name 'ColumnC'.
If I run just the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS line individually and then rerun the whole query, I get the output I expect. This feels like a quirk/error in SSMS. Is there anything I can do to force it not to ignore the DROP statement?

This doesn't have anything to do with SSMS, but SQL Server. The data engine is compiling your batch at at the time of that compilation the table has two columns, not three, and so you get an error. Separate your statements into different batches.

Thanks! Sure enough, inserting a "GO" after the drop statement fixes the problem.
